# How to encrypt a string using RSA scheme?

Tags: python, encryption, hash, rsa

I am using a tutorial for RSA implementation from this site: https://sahandsaba.com/cryptography-rsa-part-1.html

They use this function for encryption:

```
def power(x, m, n):
    """Calculate x^m modulo n using O(log(m)) operations."""
    a = 1
    while m > 0:
        if m % 2 == 1:
            a = (a * x) % n
        x = (x * x) % n
        m //= 2
    return a

def rsa_encrypt(message, n, e):
    return modular.power(message, e, n)
```

and then he encrypts a number:

```
>>> message = 123
>>> cipher = rsa_encrypt(message, n, e)
```

How do I encrypt entire String though? I want to encrypt string generated by a hash using this implementation.

Comment: strings are characters, characters have an ascii value `ord('B')` - value which is an integer. build a chain that conversts `string -> ord -> rsa  and rsa -> ord -> string` - Hashes are normally not reversable, so you will only be able to restore the hash - not the original string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two functions you are missing are those for going from a sequence of bytes to a number, and back:

```
def bytes2num(b):
    return b[0] + 256 * bytes2num(b[1:]) if b else 0

def num2bytes(n):
    return bytes([n % 256]) + num2bytes(n // 256) if n else b''
```

If you want to work with strings you can define the functions:

```
def str2num(s):
    return bytes2num(s.encode('utf-8'))

def num2str(n):
    return num2bytes(n).decode('utf-8')
```

You should make those implementations iterative if your messages are very long.

Test:

```
>>> s = 'Hello, world!'

>>> str2num(s)
2645608968347327576478451524936

>>> num2str(2645608968347327576478451524936)
'Hello, world!'
```

Comment: So I don't need to split this string into blocksize smaller than key size?

Comment: No, you don't need to split the string in blocks. See also this question: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/32344/how-to-determine-rsa-block-size-for-decryption

Comment: You can not encrypt data larger than the key size, the data length must be shorter than the key.

Comment: So I just generate the hash using some hash function, then I encrypt str2num(hash) using private key and I get digital signature? No need to split? awesome, thanks. Could you explain the str2num function, please?

Comment: The hash data must be shorter than the key, if that is true there is no need to split the hash. IN can event splitting data into multiple RSA encryptions is in general wrong.

Comment: @sushionthefork: It creates a big number from the bytes values. If the byte sequence `s` is composed of <b0, b1, b2, ..., bN>, then the number representing it is b0*256^0+b1*256^1+b2*256^2+...+bN*256^N

Comment: @sushionthefork: as a further clarification, you can see the byte sequence just as a base256 number, so that's the usual conversion to/from base10.

Comment: may I ask what does `if b else 0` mean in the code `return b[0] + 256 * bytes2num(b[1:]) if b else 0`?

Comment: It's an inline `if`. Another way to write that would be `if b: return b[0] + 256 * bytes2num(b[1:]); else: return 0`. Returning 0 when the byte sequence is empty is the base case of that recursive function.

Comment: Your edited version with bytes doesn't work for me when I try to decode it. I am on OS X. It just prints bytes out. When I delete .decode('utf-8') part, it works the same.

Comment: Works on my machine (I am on OS X too). Can you open a new question with a [mcve]?

Comment: @fferri In python 3 (which I assume you're using, due to the str/bytes naming), you can replace the custom logic of `bytes2num`/`num2bytes` with builtins: `int.from_bytes(b, 'little')` and `n.to_bytes((n.bit_length() - 1) // 8 + 1, 'little')`, respectively.

Comment: my bad, I had python 2 as default interpreter and it didn't work, with python3 it work nicely, thanks